# C++11, copying just one field into a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Say I have the following struct in C++

```
struct Foo {
   double a;
   int b;
};
```

And say I have a parameter to some function declared as follows:

```
const std::initializer_list<Foo> &args;
```

Is there an concise way to extract just one field from the elements in `args`  to get, for instance, just an std::vector containing each `b` field from the original `args` list?

Of course, I know I could do this by just explicitly writing it out as a loop:

```
std::vector<int> result;
for(auto &x:args) {
    result.push_back(x.b);
}
```

... but given that I can copy an entire initializer_list of any type to a like-typed vector in a single line of C++, just using functions like std::copy and std::back_inserter,  I am  wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this as well, using stl or C++11 facilities that may already exist.

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are misusing `initializer_list`! It suppose to be used as initialization of some specific object. Now your case is doing something different. Why? We do not know, since this is  question with XY problem.

Comment: Have you tried `std::transform`?

Comment: `std::transform(std::begin(args), std::end(args), std::back_inserter(result), [] (const Foo & foo) { return foo.b; });`

Comment: @pmaxim98 - The answer section is bellow. And may I suggest `std::mem_fn(&Foo::b)` instead? In this case I find it better than a lambda. Purely for lack of verbosity.

Comment: Interesting, how does `std::mem_fn(&Foo::b)` work here?

Comment: @pmaxim98 - Despite the un-intuitive name, `std::mem_fn` can be used to generate an accessor for a member of any type. In this case, it will simply return `b`. I personally like it better than spelling the lambda out. Even though the end result is the same.

Comment: @StoryTeller I never saw this function before, hence my question, and indeed it seems perfect here. I kind of like it more too because of the same reasons you given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::transform` and add elements to the vector via `std::back_inserter`:

```
std::transform(std::begin(args), std::end(args), std::back_inserter(result), 
[] (const Foo & foo) { return foo.b; });
```

If you find the lambda too verbose you can use `std::mem_fn` instead (credit goes to [@StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller)).

```
std::transform(std::begin(args), std::end(args), std::back_inserter(result), std::mem_fn(&Foo::b));
```

But then again, your approach isn't necessary bad since it's pretty readable and does the job just fine (might have some performance issues tho).

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be using [linq++](https://github.com/hjiang/linqxx/wiki) like the following:

```
shared_ptr<vector<Foo>> foo_list; 
// suppose foo_list is being filled
shared_ptr<vector> bs = from(foo_list).select(&_1 ->* &Foo::b).get();
```